# Trying to get users with their respective role but returns Class 'Role' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, entrust

I'm on [Laravel 5.4](https://laravel.com) and using [Zizaco Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) to handle roles and permissions in my app and I'm trying to pull all users that has a role of 'user' but it returns me this error

> (1/1) FatalErrorException
>
> Class 'Role' not found in
>
> HasRelationships.php (line 487)

and here's my query

```
use App\User; //declare user model

$customer = User::with('roles')->get();
```

and my User model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use EntrustUserTrait;
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'email', 'password', 'real_password', 'first_name'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token', 'real_password'
    ];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Role','assigned_roles');
    }

}
```

the role model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole;

class Role extends EntrustRole
{

}
```

and the entrust config

```
<?php

/**
 * This file is part of Entrust,
 * a role & permission management solution for Laravel.
 *
 * @license MIT
 * @package Zizaco\Entrust
 */

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Entrust Role Model
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the Role model used by Entrust to create correct relations.  Update
    | the role if it is in a different namespace.
    |
    */
    'role' => 'App\Role',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Entrust Roles Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the roles table used by Entrust to save roles to the database.
    |
    */
    'roles_table' => 'roles',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application User Model
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the User model used by Entrust to create correct relations.
    | Update the User if it is in a different namespace.
    |
    */
    'user' => 'App\User',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Users Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the users table used by the application to save users to the
    | database.
    |
    */
    'users_table' => 'users',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Entrust Permission Model
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the Permission model used by Entrust to create correct relations.
    | Update the permission if it is in a different namespace.
    |
    */
    'permission' => 'App\Permission',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Entrust Permissions Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the permissions table used by Entrust to save permissions to the
    | database.
    |
    */
    'permissions_table' => 'permissions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Entrust permission_role Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the permission_role table used by Entrust to save relationship
    | between permissions and roles to the database.
    |
    */
    'permission_role_table' => 'permission_role',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Entrust role_user Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the role_user table used by Entrust to save assigned roles to the
    | database.
    |
    */
    'role_user_table' => 'role_user',


];
```

Any ideas, help please?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure package has an entry in `composer.json`.

Check that the service provider is registered.

Then, regenerate autoload class map by running:

```
composer dump-autoload
```